# How to get the column name of selected max/min value (i.e. second largest/smallest) across row by dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

As the title, How do I get the column name of the second/third largest/smallest value across rows by `dplyr`?
(Note!: compare value from gp1 to gp3, I modify the orginal data)

One way is use `apply` in base R:

```
a <- data.frame(name=letters[1:9], gp1=c(3:11), gp2=c(1:9), gp3=c(8,8,2,6,6,6,12,12,6))
##
##   name gp1 gp2 gp3
## 1    a   3   1   8
## 2    b   4   2   8
## 3    c   5   3   2
## 4    d   6   4   6
## 5    e   7   5   6
## 6    f   8   6   6
## 7    g   9   7  12
## 8    h  10   8  12
## 9    i  11   9   6

a$max1_colname <- apply(a, 1, function(t) colnames(a)[which.max(t)])
## There will be some warnings. the problem of name column? 
##
##   name gp1 gp2 gp3 max1_colname
## 1    a   3   1   8          gp3
## 2    b   4   2   8          gp3
## 3    c   5   3   2          gp1
## 4    d   6   4   6          gp1
## 5    e   7   5   6          gp1
## 6    f   8   6   6          gp1
## 7    g   9   7  12          gp3
## 8    h  10   8  12          gp3
## 9    i  11   9   6          gp1
```

How could I accomplish it by using `dplyr` (ignore the 4th row has two max values) and how about the second largest column name?

Extra:
More complex, if there are two max largest value (such as 4th row), how could I get the result as follow:

```
##
##   name gp1 gp2 gp3 max1_colname
## 1    a   3   1   8          gp3
## 2    b   4   2   8          gp3
## 3    c   5   3   2          gp1
## 4    d   6   4   6          gp1+gp3
## 5    e   7   5   6          gp1
## 6    f   8   6   6          gp1
## 7    g   9   7  12          gp3
## 8    h  10   8  12          gp3
## 9    i  11   9   6          gp1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max.col` inside a `mutate` call. Note that this will keep only one value, and ties can be handled with `ties.method`. By default, it picks one tied maximum randomly.

```r
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  mutate(max1_colname = names(select(., gp1:gp3))[max.col(select(., gp1:gp3))])
```

---

For your second, more complex case, you can do this:

```r
a %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max1_colname = paste(names(select(., -name))[c_across(-name) == max(c_across(-name))], collapse = "+"))

#   name    gp1   gp2   gp3 max1_colname
# 1 a         3     1     8 gp3         
# 2 b         4     2     8 gp3         
# 3 c         5     3     2 gp1         
# 4 d         6     4     6 gp1+gp3     
# 5 e         7     5     6 gp1         
# 6 f         8     6     6 gp1         
# 7 g         9     7    12 gp3         
# 8 h        10     8    12 gp3         
# 9 i        11     9     6 gp1
```

---

To get the second (or more) maximum, use `order` with `decreasing = TRUE`:

```r
a %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max2_colname = names(.)[order(c_across(everything()), decreasing = TRUE)[2]])

#     gp1   gp2   gp3 max2_colname
# 1     3     1     8 gp1         
# 2     4     2     8 gp1         
# 3     5     3     2 gp2         
# 4     6     4     6 gp3         
# 5     7     5     6 gp3         
# 6     8     6     6 gp2         
# 7     9     7    12 gp1         
# 8    10     8    12 gp1         
# 9    11     9     6 gp2
```

---

For an even more complex case where you want both an `n`th maximum and to get all of them, you can use `dense_rank` + `which`:

```r
a %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max1_colname = paste(names(.)[which(dense_rank(-c_across(everything())) == 2)], collapse = "+"))

#     gp1   gp2   gp3 max1_colname
# 1     3     1     8 gp1         
# 2     4     2     8 gp1         
# 3     5     3     2 gp2         
# 4     6     4     6 gp2         
# 5     7     5     6 gp3         
# 6     8     6     6 gp2+gp3     
# 7     9     7    12 gp1         
# 8    10     8    12 gp1         
# 9    11     9     6 gp2
```

Comment: Nice, much shorter solution for the second part!

Comment: How about the second largest column name?

Comment: Check the edit. You can use `order`

Comment: IF there are extra column, it will wrong. So I change the data of my question.

Comment: In that case, you just need to remove it from the selection, i.e. instead of `everything()`, use `-name`

Comment: Do you mean `names(.)[names(.)%in%c('gp1','gp2','gp3')][which.max(c_across(c(gp1, gp2, gp3)))]`? Or other solutions? It is too long.

Comment: This can be further simplified. You can use `select` and `tidyselect` verbs. I edited my answer for the first two cases.

Answer (score 2):

The first part can be accomplished by:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max1_colname = names(.)[which.max(c_across(everything()))])

gp1 gp2 gp3 max1_colname
3   1   8   gp3
4   2   8   gp3
5   3   2   gp1
6   4   6   gp1
7   5   6   gp1
8   6   6   gp1
9   7   12  gp3
10  8   12  gp3
11  9   6   gp1
```

A solution for the second part:

```
a1 <- a %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id)

a2 <- a1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  top_n(value, n = 1) %>% 
  mutate(max1_colname = paste0(name, collapse = "+")) %>% 
  select(id, max1_colname) %>% 
  distinct()
  
a1 %>% 
  left_join(a2, by = c("id")) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  relocate(max1_colname, .after = gp3) %>% 
  select(-id) 

gp1 gp2 gp3 max1_colname
3   1   8   gp3
4   2   8   gp3
5   3   2   gp1
6   4   6   gp1+gp3
7   5   6   gp1
8   6   6   gp1
9   7   12  gp3
10  8   12  gp3
11  9   6   gp1
```

Answer (score 2):

Also note there is a base `max.col` function, the only thing is it returns one index (can be set to first, last, random).

```
a %>%
  mutate(max1_colname = paste("grp", max.col(.), sep = ""))

#   gp1 gp2 gp3 max1_colname
# 1   3   1   8         grp3
# 2   4   2   8         grp3
# 3   5   3   2         grp1
# 4   6   4   6         grp1
# 5   7   5   6         grp1
# 6   8   6   6         grp1
# 7   9   7  12         grp3
# 8  10   8  12         grp3
# 9  11   9   6         grp1
```